# Why is my entire site a tiny bit smaller in Firefox?

Tags: css, firefox

In typical web design fashion, there's always something that doesn't look quite right between two browsers. This one just completely lost me though.

I open the site in Safari. Everything is dandy.

I open it in Firefox. The entire page is displayed, just fine, but about 10-20% smaller. Images, fonts, divs. Everything.

Does this make any sense to anyone? Have you seen it or fixed it before? Is it just this browser? Is it me? Have I finally lost my mind?

Comment: I like the insanity tag. That's something I often feel when dealing with things that don't look right between browsers, or even in one browser.

Comment: I guess Rich didn't feel the same way.

Comment: Tough turtles. I'm bringin' it back.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You may have zoomed firefox's view by accident, <kbd>ctrl-+</kbd> will increase the size, <kbd>ctrl--</kbd> will decrease the size. To reset it, hit <kbd>ctrl-0</kbd>.

As Brian has commented on this answer, you certainly shouldn't rely on the size being the same, though I'm sure you're aware of the perils of designing for a particular size. It's good to know that you are seeing what you intended though.

Comment: That fixed it. I figured it was me being dumb like that somehow. Thanks!

Comment: Even though this was your problem, keep in mind when designing that some users might be using this feature of Firefox.

Answer (score 2):

You should never expect a website to look exactly the same, cross browser, cross OS, etc. etc.  Some people will have smaller or larger resolutions, others will have text size zoomed in or out.  Therefore you should always keep these things in mind when designing your website!  Don't design for pixel, but for more fluid layouts.

Comment: It shouldn't look like this though. I'm pretty decent at WebKit-Gecko compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you press <kbd>CTRL-0</kbd> or select View → Zoom → Reset?